# Мошейничество

Tags: другое

Часто встречаю написание "мошейничество" вместо "мошенничество". 
Откуда такая ошибка? Как-то можно объяснить природу такого написания?

Answer (score 2):

Могу предположить, что вариант "мошейник" - это просторечное произношение, неоправданная вставка звуков. Похоже на ошейник, лишайник и др.

http://studopedia.net/2_49423_opravdannaya-i-neopravdannaya-vstavka-zvukov.html

"Причиной неоправданной вставки гласного, согласного может служить неправильно понятая этимология (происхождение) слова или трудное для произношения сочетание звуков. Иногда неоправданная вставка звука связана с неправильно понятой словообразовательной структурой слова, с неверным сближением данного слова с другими словами, близкими по значению".

Мне кажется, что вставка Й имеет фонетическую причину: "мошейник"  легче произнести , чем "мошенник", здесь звук Й как бы обеспечивает плавный переход к звуку Н.

Comment: @Vera. У ОШЕЙНИКА и ЛИШАЙНИКА никогда и нигде не встречались формы ОШЕ-Н-НИК и ЛИША-Н-НИК или что-то другое , вариантное . И  не  наблюдается какой-либо легкости в произношении вставкой Й вместо первой Н . И это только детям легче произносить ЛЕПЕСТРИЧЕСТВО вместо ЭЛЕКТРИЧЕСТВО или БИБИЗЬЯНА вместо ОБЕЗЬЯНА . Только детям . А @Зануда , насколько можно понять , имеет в виду именно текстовое написание , а не разговорную речь .

Comment: Да, я имею в виду написание, но написание может быть обусловлено произношением.
Часто встречаю не в литературных текстах, а в электронных письмах на тему "мошейничества".

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, это искажение в целях облегчения произношения. Как дуршлаг - друшлаг. Или неверная ассоциация со словом "мошенник".

Answer (score 1):

Попробую высказать следующее предположение . <<**МОШЕННИЧЕСТВО**>> это от слова <<**МОШНА**>> . МОШНА = МЕШОК С ДЕНЬГАМИ / КОШЕЛЁК . Понятно , что мешок для хранения денег шился не из обычной мешковины или холста , а из дорогой ткани . Возможно из **шёлка** , - эта ткань и нежная и прочная . Сотрим разъяснение в ПЦСС стр. 318 [link text](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0318.htm)   Как видим , *шёлк* указывается . ==================================================================================== [image]================================================================================================================= Теперь наберём ивритными буквами (справа-налево) : **מ**  *мем*  =М , **ש**  *шин* =Ш/С  , **י** *йуд* =Й и введём в ИРИС-словарь [link text](http://www.slovar.co.il/translate.php). Получим перевод на русский  :  << **ШЁЛК** >> , читается , как  <<*МЕШИ*>> .   [image] ====================================================================================== Однако , в побуквенном прочтении (русскими буквами : **М**-**Ш**-**Й** ) может быть прочитано и как <<**МОШЕЙ**>> ; в класическом иврите нет гласных букв , как таковых , и огласовка произвдится читающим самостоятельно . Таким образом , мы выводим происхождение слова  <<**МОШНА**>> от ивритного <<**ШЁЛК**>> , как ткани , употреблявшейся для изготовления *мешочных кошельков* .  И <<**МОШЕЙНИЧЕСТВО**>> ( МОШ-Й-НИЧЕСТВО , вместо общераспространённого *МОШЕ-Н-НИЧЕСТВО* )  это суть словесная форма , более приближенная к ивритному первоисходнику , - присутствие буквы **Й**  , соответственно ивритному  **י** *йуд* .

Comment: Может быть. Но люди, допускающие такое произношение, вряд ли так глубоко мыслят. Особенно, если это дети.

Comment: @Инна. Я исхожу из того, что @Зануда, задавший вопрос о "мошейничестве", выразился словами "Часто встречается написание "мошейничество"...". То есть, речь идёт о написании, а не о произношении, особенно детском. Должно быть, @Зануда. сталкивался с таким вариантным написанием в литературных или иных текстах. /// Я, например, тоже сталкивался в иконописи и др. записях с написанием ЕВФРЕМ (Е-в-фрем) вместо церковно-канонической формы ЕФРЕМ (Е-фрем без В). И хорошо известное имя ЕФИМ и фамилия ЕФИМОВ тоже отличаются написанием от канонической именной формы - там ЕВФИМИЙ (Е-в-фим, с В).